# How to load otf font file by filename (using absolute path on windows)

Tags: luaotfload

I use texlive 2016 on windows (TeXStudio/latexmk/lualatex). The following MWE worked for me until the last texlive 2016 update (tlmgr update --all; executed 26th january 2017).

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}

\setmainfont{EB Garamond}[%
Extension = .otf ,
Path= C:/Users/me/Documents/MWEs/fonts/EBGaramond-0.016/otf/ , %<-- does not work anymore
%Path= fonts/EBGaramond-0.016/otf/ , %<-- relative path works fine
Numbers = {OldStyle,Monospaced},
UprightFont = {EBGaramond08-Regular},
ItalicFont = {EBGaramond08-Italic},
UprightFeatures = {%
    SizeFeatures={%
        {Size={-9.99},Font={EBGaramond08-Regular}},
        {Size={10-},Font={EBGaramond12-Regular}},
    },
},
ItalicFeatures = {%
    SizeFeatures={%
        {Size={-9.99},Font={EBGaramond08-Italic}},
        {Size={10-},Font={EBGaramond12-Italic}},
    },
},
]

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{english}

\begin{document}

Hello World!

\end{document}
```

After the above mentioned update luaotfload does not load (found) the otf-file any more. From the log:

luaotfload | db : Reload initiated (formats: otf,ttf,ttc); reason: "File not found: C.".

Just a guess: 'C.".' looks strange to me - perhaps a parsing problem?

If I eliminate the leading "C:/.../..." and use a relative path instead, luaotfload finds the file and everything works fine.

Note: The font EB Garamond can be used free of charge and is only used for demonstration purposes. It can be downloaded here: http://www.georgduffner.at/ebgaramond/download.html

Are absolute paths not supported (anymore, at least on windows)?

Comment: I suggest adding the `fontspec` flag to your post. There was a major fontspec change in January. Some minor issues have been noticed, and an update is already under way, according to one of its developers.

Comment: the update was yesterday but I suspect this is a luaotfload issue, but can't test as I don't have a windows texllve.  There was a new fontspec in texlive, probably this morning depending on your mirror, but I don't think it will affect this. Can you confirm if it is all fonts fail with a `c:/` path or something about this one?

Comment: You can try `Path=/Users/me/Documents/MWEs/fonts/EBGaramond-0.016/otf/`...

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Yes, I've seen and received a fontspec update this morning. But the problem still exists. All fonts loaded using "C:/..." are affected (I have not tested D:/..., as I store all my fonts on C:-drive).

Comment: @PaulGaborit This seems to work.

Comment: @lAtExFaN It's just a workaround.

Comment: possibly same as this issue https://github.com/wspr/fontspec/issues/262

Comment: Has anyone an idea whether a fix exists and when will it be available via ctan (I followed the github discussion and tlmgr-updated today, but: although I received a luaotfload update (Ver­sion num­ber: 2.8-fix-1 2017-02-04), the above MWE does not compile using "Path=c:/..." - perhaps the syntax for absolute win32-paths has changed?)

Comment: I see: fontspec v2.5e should solve this issue. From the changelog "... Fix regression in which C:\... file paths in Windows couldn't be used. ...". As 2.5e has been released on Feb. 10th, I hope it appears on ctan soon (cause I also was affected from the "bug ... in \newopentypefeature")

Comment: @DavidCarlisle the latest TL2016 update solved the problem. Should I delete this question?

Comment: possibly, as the bug was only distributed for a few days. or you could self-answer saying it is fixed in the latest release if you think others may still be caught out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was caused by a bug/regression in the fontspec package. It was fixed in fontspec v2.5e (2017/02/10).

From the changelog:
"Fix regression in which C:... file paths in Windows couldn't be used."